# Can't populate variable from command in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables, command, opensuse

I'm new to bash scripting, and I'm working on a script where the user enters a username and gets a list of the associated information from /etc/passwd. Unfortunately, I seem to be having trouble populating a variable from a command. The error message I'm getting suggests the if statement isn't being entered into, but I'm not sure why.

The script currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#readifs

FILE=/etc/passwd

read -p "Enter a username > " user_name

file_info=$(grep "^$user_name:" $FILE)

if [ -n "$file_info" ]; then
     IFS=":" read user pw uid gid name home shell <<< "$file_info"
     echo "User = '$user'"
     echo "UID = '$UID'"
     echo "GID = '$GID'"
     echo "Full Name = '$name'"
     echo "Shell = '$shell'"
else
     echo "No such user '$user_name'" > &2
     exit 1
fi
```

When I run it, using a valid username, I get the following two lines:

```
readifs.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
readifs.sh: line 20: `  echo "No such user '$user_name'" > &2'
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, or doing something bash doesn't allow but I'm too new to catch. Can anyone point out and correct the error in my script?

Comment: `>&2`. Take out the space. And going forward, please make a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: Also, since your exclusive target is Linux, you'll have a better time of it using `user_info=$(getent passwd "$user_name")` instead of grepping `/etc/passwd`; the `getent` approach will work even on systems that are using NIS, LDAP, or other directory stores other than `/etc/passwd`. I'd also consider making it more direct: `IFS=: read user pw uid gid name home shell _ < <(getent passwd "$user_name")` avoids reading the whole string into a variable only to split it out later.

Comment: (Voting to close-as-typo, w/ the stray space as a cause).

Comment: (As another aside -- executables shouldn't have filename extensions. Just as you don't run `ls.elf`, so your script should be called `readifs`, not `readifs.sh`. If this were a *shell library*, intended to be sourced rather than executed, an extension would be appropriate... but even then, that extension should be `.bash`, not `.sh`, unless your code is written with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang).

Comment: Thanks, Duffy, for pointing me towards shellcheck.net. I wasn't aware of that resource, but I'll definitely use it in the future.

Comment: Although the >&2 typo is a good catch, it still doesn't explain why I'm getting to that line at all. The username I enter at the read line, intentionally from stdin, isn't making it through the process of finding the user info and printing it back out.

Comment: So -- I'd suggest reducing this to a [mcve] that doesn't have any unrelated bugs or code not directly necessary to directly reproduce the immediate question at hand. For example, something closer would be `user_name='root'; file_info=$(grep "^user_name:" /etc/passwd); if [ -n "$file_info" ]; then echo "THIS SHOULD BE REACHED"; else echo "THIS SHOULD NOT BE REACHED"; fi` -- asking why `THIS SHOULD NOT BE REACHED` is printed would be a much clearer question.

Comment: That way it doesn't depend on runtime behavior (exactly what the username that's entered is, exactly which usernames are present on the system), and is something other people have a chance of being able to run themselves to see the behavior at hand.

Comment: If you're having trouble building a MCVE, run the script with `bash -x yourscript` to log each command it invokes; that way you can see the first command that differs from what you expect, and focus your question around that point. The "Tricks for Trimming" section at http://sscce.org/ is also often helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Charles Duffy for all the great feedback on not just this script, but bash scripting and Stack Overflow in general.

I was able to fix the script as I wanted. I removed the ^ and : from the file_info line, which was stopping the grep command from finding the line I wanted. I also renamed $UID and $GID to use lower case letters, and removed the space in "> &2".

Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: `grep "$user_name"` is probably not going to do what you want in the corner cases. If you're looking for `someuser1`, you don't want it to match `someuser12` instead. Consider the suggestion of using `getent` reiterated. `awk -v user_name="$user_name" -F: '$1 == user_name { print $0; exit; }' </etc/passwd` is another alternative that will limit the search to an exact match (vs a regex), and only on the first field.